# How to use setter for nested field

Tags: java

I want to set value for a field which is in a nested class. How can I set the value for abc field in the code below ? Thanks.

I have the following code

```
public class A {
    private String a1;
    private B b;

    public String geta1(){
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public B getB(){
        return B;
    }

    public void setB(B b){
        this.B = b;
    }
}

public class B {
    private String abc;

    public String getabc(){
        return abc;
    }

    public String setabc(String value){
        this.abc = abc;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public void useMethod() {
        A data = new A();
        data.setB().setabc("value");
    }
}
```

Comment: How's this question related to `json` and `gson` tags?

Comment: Also are you sure you're using nested class ? I don't see any nesting basically

Comment: @funkyjelly he means a composition I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set Object B first you need to create it then get the object from A class then set the value for the abc

```
public class Test {
    public void useMethod() {
        A data = new A();
        data.setB(new B());
        data.getB().setabc("value");
    }
  }
```

And change this method this.B = b; to this.b =b;

Answer (score 0):

Either linked

```
data.getB().setAbc("abc");
```

Or if you want a more unified interface

```
class A {
     //other stuff
    public void setAbc(String value) {
        if (b != null) {
             b.setAbc(value);
        }
        //error handling if b is null?
    }
}
```

and then

```
data.setB(new B());
data.setAbc("ABC");
```